# Xamarin Forms Android This type of collectionView does not support changes to its sourceCollection from a thread different from the dispatcher thread

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, archive

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to archive my app for deployment.

[image: error on archive]
This error doesn't show up at any other time. The project builds and runs on emulators and devices without issue. This error has zero context or direction as to where to look to fix it. It also just randomly showed up out of nowhere, last time I built/archived (with zero functional changes) this error did not happen.

Main difference between this archival and the previous one is a newer version of VS 2017. Don't remember exactly the version from before, but am currently on 15.9.4 (stable).

Looking around on the interwebs, I've found that this error seems to have something to do with ObservableCollection's, which there are probably 10-ish in my app. Not really sure what to do here, because this has never been an issue previously, and I'm coming up on a deadline and with the structure of the app, am not in a good position to start making functional changes.

***EDIT***

I have also cleaned and rebuilt my solution, as well as deleting all bin/obj folders in my xamarin projects. Even tried deleting the .vs folder which can sometimes help. But still no go.

Going to try updating VS to 15.9.5 and see if maybe it was fixed in a release.

***EDIT 2***

Updating VS 2017 to 15.9.5 made no difference.

***EDIT 3***

I had my coworker try archiving the exact same project on his machine (running VS 2017: 5.9.3, and it archived fine for him. So far that's the only difference we've been able to find between our environments.

Comment: Did you try to use "repair" in Visual Studio installer(open Visual Studio installer,click "more",click the repair)? If this issue is still existed, you can refer to this link,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017, then install an earlier release VS 2017

Comment: Attempting now. Really hope it works, because it's a huge inconvenience to have to restore VS.

Comment: in my case if check MultiDex option in compile configuration it's return to works... try and good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the same problem using VS2017 15.9.9. Even the same code that could be archived a week ago threw the above mentioned error. It seems related to local data in the solution. A "clear" build was not sufficient. However manual deletion of the local obj and bin folders followed by archiving (build is done implicitly) solved the problem for me.

Comment: This seems to be the most consistent solution. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't help me either.  I've deleted bin, obj, .vs, cleaned, cycled VS, etc.  Quite stuck.

Answer (score 2):

For my part closing Visual studio and deleting the .vs hidden folder did it.

It's actually a fix for many issues using Xamarin.

I had this other issue where I couldn't archive because the build process would just hang and never end. Deleting the .vs folder did it too.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1760

Answer (score 1):

Just go to project property then go to Android options-> Select Advanced then increase the Java Max heap size to 2G/3G -> it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Leon Lu's suggestion worked. I don't particularly like it, as it took forever and repairing basically restores you to a base install (no extensions or personalizations). Took about 1.2 hours to complete, but once done I was able to again archive my android application. I guess something went wrong in vs at some point, perhaps during an update. There's no way to tell.

Comment: Actually turns out this wasn't a complete fix, I'm back to not being able to build with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ALL of the ideas above, but had no consistent reliable luck with any of them.
I found that Microsoft has had the problem reported to them (see link below).  After a ton of time burn on this, I posted at the link below one way that I've been able to get around this archive-build issue.

Like the other fixes, it's not exactly logical, and nothing that you would think would work, but I've found the process to be repeatable, which is golden for me with tight timelines and having no time for this.

[MS Visual Studio Developer Community Problem 507708](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/507708/archive-apps-in-vs-2017-15910-not-working.html)

Posted on a Saturday morning, a sign of really needing to get around this urgently.  I hope it helps you too.